# After removed H atoms in MarvinSketch and MayaChemTools RDKitStandardizeMolecules.py, got lots of CH2 flags in ChemDraw

Tags: cheminformatics

I downloaded the [SDF](https://www.ebi.ac.uk/chebi/searchId.do?chebiId=CHEBI:2909) of atisine structure and imported it into my ChemDraw. From there, I basically made the skeleton of it (SMILES `C12C3(CCCC2CN4CCOC34)C5C6(CCC(CC6)C5)CC1`) and exported it to a new SDF. The new SDF was opened with [DataWarrior](https://openmolecules.org/datawarrior) and I ran the conformer generator. Here is the result in ChemDraw.
[image]

I tried to remove all hydrogens present using [ChemAxon MarvinSketch](https://chemaxon.com/products/marvin). Here are the pictures of before and after the hydrogens removed. So far, it was working as expected.

[image]
[image]

However, here we go, there are lots of CH2 labels here. I know these atoms are CH2 indeed and those are chemically correct but why it does have to be expanded while other CH2 atoms are remain hidden. Those shown CH2 should not appear though so I thought the MarvinSketch was not removed the hydrogens correctly.

[image]

In another attempt, I tried to use [MayaChemTools RDKitStandardizeMolecules.py](http://www.mayachemtools.org/Download.html) and ran `./RDKitStandardizeMolecules.py --standardizeParams "cleanupRemoveHydrogens,yes" -i atisineminimal_mmff941.sdf -o atisineminimal_mmff941clean.sdf` in Terminal. Here is the result in ChemDraw.
[image]

I think it is the fault of these MarvinSketch and RDKit because the DataWarrior-generated SDF doesn't make any CH2 labels, nor does the original and modified SDF of atisine.

Anyone have a better way to remove these hydrogens without making those CH2?

Comment: I have already put the SDF of all files (initial, DataWarrior-generated, MarvinSketch, and RDKit) on here https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1KeQMxjJTWi4pCGleMhZAd3fhk0frwWs7?usp=sharing

Comment: not a ChemDraw user, but it looks to me like the explicit labelling of particular carbons happens when the bonds extend in an almost-linear fashion out the top and bottom. The labels might just be saying 'theres a carbon here' instead of the other interpretation - a really long bond

Comment: @làntèrn regarding your last comment, please see this (if you want the question to remain open): https://mattermodeling.meta.stackexchange.com/q/393/5. If you no longer actively need an answer, that's okay too, but let us know! Have you already found an answer? If so please write an answer since it would be helpful for future users! I already gave my +1 long ago, I'm just here seeking an update on the status of this question since it has been more than 6 months :)